# Show "Loading..." Message while Downloader is working (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, while-loop

In my vb.net Application id like to implement a feature that makes some kind of "LOading..." Message pop up while the WebClient is downloading stuff. I tried using a While statement:

```
dim dl as New Net.Webclient
dl.DonwloadString("any")
While dl.isBusy
'Do something
```

But that didnt work, obviously because the While statement is handled once the download is finished already. Any solutions on that?

Comment: Have you tried using a background worker? .You can start the download on a separate thread and show the message box from your current thread.

Comment: Oh thats a good idea, ill try that.

Comment: Use the non-blocking [`DownloadStringAsync()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead. It raises the [`DownloadStringCompleted` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstringcompleted?view=netframework-4.7.2) when the string has been downloaded, then use [`e.Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.downloadstringcompletedeventargs?view=netframework-4.7.2) inside the event handler to fetch the string.

Comment: [This](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?869567) may interest you.

Comment: You could also use [DownloadDataAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloaddataasync) which provides a [DownloadProgressChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged) event. This event can be used to update the UI, showing the progress. Also, mind that `DownloadString` without specifying an Encoding will use the Default (local) Encoding. The string you receive might not be what you're expecting, depending on the orginal Encoding.

Comment: @Jimi the String I want to query is always in a plain format (pastebin raw) so that should work fine

Comment: PasteBin text encoding is UTF-8. `DownloadDataAsync` returns the resource you specified without any conversion or specific encoding. A Stream is always a Byte array, the string format is a conversion of the Byte array using the default encoding; the Local one, if you didn't specify one explicitly. That method allows to have an async progress update while the data is downloaded, with the  `DownloadProgressChanged` event. Anyway, if you plan to download from PasteBin, you hardly need a progress bar or similar. Unless you plan a mass download. In any case, my suggestion stands.